# How to include externally loaded script to all bundles created by React.lazy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted divide my project into two bundles. Here's my simplified **App.js**

```
import React, { Suspense, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import loadGif from './images/731.gif';

const HospitalDashboard = React.lazy(() => import('./HospitalDashboard'));
const OperatorDashboard = React.lazy(() => import('./OperatorDashboard'));

function App () {

    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState(null);

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<img className='load' src={loadGif}/>}>
            {credentials.role == 'operator' ? 
                <OperatorDashboard/> :
                <HospitalDashboard/>}
        </Suspense>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and here's my simplified **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js?version=256"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Both in *OperatorDashboard* and *HospitalDashboard* I am using daterangepicker followingly:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
...
useEffect(()=>{
    $('#datePicker').daterangepicker(initOptions,onCallback)
},[])
```

In *HospitalDashboard* everything works fine but in *OperatorDashboard* I am getting this error:
**jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).daterangepicker is not a function**

It is somehow related to React.lazy and bundles but I don't know how to solve it. If I use ordinary import without React.lazy, everything works fine again. Thanks for help!

Comment: You're supposed to include all your dependencies into [respective section of your package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies). Otherwise, webpack won't be able to build up its dependency tree. You may add those manually (editing package.json and doing `npm i` / `yarn`) or doing `npm i daterangepicker` or `yarn add daterangepicker`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But for some other reasons I can't use npm package [daterangepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daterangepicker). I need to use daterangepicker.min.js script.

Comment: You have a bit unconventional set up I must say (and I would expect you'll run in all sorts of weird issues further down the line). However, solution to your particular problem may be referring to `window.daterangepicker()` (or any other dependency brought in from external scripts, for that matter) instead of doing `import daterangepicker`.

Comment: I have just deleted one line of code, which could be misleading. Point is, that I need to use daterangepicker totally 'outside' of React - not as a react element but just as a jQuery library.